# Como eliminar elementos de una lista

Tags: android, android-studio, lista, arraylist

tengo una clase que crea círculos cada vez que toco la pantalla y cuando cumple cierta condición quiero que los vaya eliminando de la lista. Como puedo hacer? Gracias.

```
    public class Juego extends SurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener {


    Circulos circulos;
    Paint paint;
    int x, y;

    List<Circulos> lista_circulos = new ArrayList<Circulos>();

    public Juego(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);

        circulos = new Circulos(this);

        paint = new Paint();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), paint);

        for (Circulos circulos : lista_circulos) {
            circulos.onDraw(canvas);
        }

        invalidate();
    }

    private Circulos crearCirculos() {
        return new Circulos(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
        y = (int) motionEvent.getY();

        crearCirculo();

        invalidate();
        return false;
    }

    public void crearCirculo(){
        lista_circulos.add(crearCirculos());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes eliminar los elementos por su indice en la lista, para evitar [ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) en este caso puedes crear una lista en la cual agregues los elementos a eliminar y al final remuevas estos elementos de la lista original.

En este caso puedes usar este método en donde puedes definir la cantidad de objetos de tu listado.

```
private void eliminarElementos(int elementos){

    //Si el numero elementos a eliminar es mayor a la cantidad de objetos
    //en la lista, asegura eliminar todos los elementos en la lista y evita
    //IndexOutOfBoundsException
    if(listaCirculos.size()< elementos){
        elementos = listaCirculos.size();
    }

    List<Circulos> listToRemove = new ArrayList<Circulos>();
    for(int i = 0; i< elementos; i++){
        listToRemove.add(listaCirculos.get(i));
    }
    listaCirculos.removeAll(listToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Si querés eliminar teniendo en cuenta el Objeto y no el índice, tenés que sobrescribir el método equal(Object ) de tu clase Círculos para que te devuelva true si es el mismo objeto. El metodo arraylist.remove(Object) utiliza el metodo equals del objeto que le estas pasando, en este caso un objeto "circulo".

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Circulo obj) {
    return (this.radio.equals(((User) obj).radio) && (this.diametro
            .equals(((User) obj).diametro)));
}
```

luego para remover

```
listaCirculos.remove(new Circulo("10","15"));
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Puede ser que sea eso. Estaba intentando eliminar los círculos con "lista_circulos.remove(0);" pero si se crean muchos me tira error. Como puedo hacer lo de equal(Object )? No entiendo como identificar a cada objeto cuando lo creo

Comment: Chelo, no veo necesaría remover una instancía de Circulo:  listaCirculos.remove(new Circulo("10","15"));

Comment: En el caso que quiera remover algún círculo en particular si, caso contrario usa tu solución. Ningún momento aclara eso.